# Calculate t from sigmoid function

Tags: function, neural-network, exponential

How can I calculate t from this sigmoid function when I have result of s(T)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use simple calculus operations and the natural log:

[image: formula]

```
s(t)     t

0,500    0
0,731    1
0,881    2
0,269   -1
0,119   -2
```